# Recorrer un Arraylist y seleccionar un objeto

Tags: java, array, arraylist, java-8, consola

Tengo el siguiente método con el que pretendo recorrer un arraylist de libros y añadirlos a una lista de reservas seleccionando el isbn seleccionado por el usuario. Una vez hecho eso, lo que pretendo hacer es que me añada el libro de la reserva al usuario que ha hecho dicha reserva. Sin embargo lo que hace el método es añadirme a todos los usuarios que tengo creados. ¿Cómo podría hacer para que solo me seleccionase al usuario que ha introducido sus datos (email y teléfono)?:

Esta es la clase usuario:

```
public class Usuario extends Persona {
    private Integer telefono;
    private String direccion;
    private Integer codigoPostal;
    private String correoElectronico;
    private ArrayList<Reserva> listaReserva;
}
```

Los valores que tengo en el Main:

```
//usuarios:
usuarioArrayList.add(new Usuario("Paco", "Martinez", "Pedro", 55, 758451267, "Calle 13", 07003, "pacomartinez@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));
6usuarioArrayList.add(new Usuario("Pamela", "Mejia", "Fontseca", 20, 68849026, "Calle Blanquerna", 07777, "pamelamejia@gmail.com", reservaArrayList));

//libros:
libroarraylist.add(new Libro("002a", "El principito", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "Editoriales Ignatius", 5, 2));
libroarraylist.add(new Libro("003a", "50 Sombras de Grey", "Sam Taylor-Wood", "Editoriales Maitus", 5, 5));
```

Esta es la clase Reserva:

```
public class Reserva {
    private Libro libro;
    private Date fechaReserva;
}
```

Y este es el método:

```
 public static void reservarLibro(ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios, ArrayList<Libro> libroArrayList, ArrayList<Reserva> reservaArrayList) {
        //Usuario.accesoUsuario(usuarios);
        System.out.print("\n Introduce tu telefono: ");
        Scanner leer1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer telefono = Integer.parseInt(leer1.nextLine());
        System.out.print("\n Introduce tu email: ");
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String email = leer.nextLine();
        int compro = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {
            if (usuarios.get(i).getTelefono().equals(telefono) && usuarios.get(i).getCorreoElectronico().equals(email)) {
                System.out.println("\n" + "Acceso correcto");
                Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
                System.out.print("\n ISBN a buscar: ");
                Scanner leer3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String isbn = leer3.nextLine();
                int comprobante = 1;
                Date fecha = new Date();
                for (int contador = 0; contador < libroArrayList.size(); contador++) {
                    if (libroArrayList.get(contador).getIsbn().equals(isbn) && libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopiasDisponibles() > 0) {
                        reservaArrayList.add(new Reserva(libroArrayList.get(contador), fecha));
                        libroArrayList.get(contador).setNumCopiasDisponibles(libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopiasDisponibles() - 1);
 usuarios.get(i).setListaReserva(reservaArrayList);

                        comprobante = 0;
                        System.out.println(libroArrayList);
                        System.out.println(reservaArrayList);
                    }
                }
                if (comprobante == 1) {
                    System.out.println("No hay copias disponibles");
                }
            }
        
        }
        if (compro == 1) {
            System.out.println("No es correcto");

        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Quita la linea                 Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
y   usuarios.get(j).setListaReserva(reservaArrayList);
no es "j" si no "i"   usuarios.get(i).setListaReserva(reservaArrayList);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void reservarLibro(ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios, ArrayList<Libro> libroArrayList, ArrayList<Reserva> reservaArrayList) {
    //Usuario.accesoUsuario(usuarios);
    System.out.print("\n Introduce tu telefono: ");
    Scanner leer1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer telefono = Integer.parseInt(leer1.nextLine());
    System.out.print("\n Introduce tu email: ");
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String email = leer.nextLine();
    int compro = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {
        if (usuarios.get(i).getTelefono().equals(telefono) && usuarios.get(i).getCorreoElectronico().equals(email)) {
            System.out.println("\n" + "Acceso correcto");
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            System.out.print("\n ISBN a buscar: ");
            Scanner leer3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String isbn = leer3.nextLine();
            int comprobante = 1;
            Date fecha = new Date();
            for (int contador = 0; contador < libroArrayList.size(); contador++) {
                if (libroArrayList.get(contador).getIsbn().equals(isbn) && libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopiasDisponibles() > 0) {
                    Reserva reserva = new Reserva(libroArrayList.get(contador), fecha);//ponerlo en una variable para que la reserva del usuario y de  la lista de reservas sea la misma
                    
                    reservaArrayList.add(reserva);//agregar el mismo libro del usuario a las reservas
                    libroArrayList.get(contador).setNumCopiasDisponibles(libroArrayList.get(contador).getNumCopiasDisponibles() - 1);
                    usuarios.get(i).getListaReserva().add(reserva);//agregar solo la reserva de ese libro al usuario
                    //si en el metodo anterior sale que la lista de reservas es nula, debes inicializarla en el constructor del usuario
                    //listaReservas = new ArrayList<>();

                    comprobante = 0;
                    compro=0;//Para que no diga que "No es correcto"
                    System.out.println(libroArrayList.get(contador));
                    System.out.println(reserva);
                    
                    //salirse de los ciclos, pues ya agregó la reserva
                    contador = libroArrayList.size();
                    i = usuarios.size();
                }
            }
            if (comprobante == 1) {
                System.out.println("No hay copias disponibles");
            }
        }
    
    }
    if (compro == 1) {
        System.out.println("No es correcto");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola sandobe! Sigue sin funcionarme, la reserva me aparece en los dos usuarios que tengo creados....

Comment: @maijava verifica entonces el telefono, lo estás guardando como entero y luego lo comparas como String, te recomiendo cambiar todos los telefonos a String, pues  no vas a hacer ninguna ecuación matemática con ellos.

Comment: Al final me funcionó con un new arraylist en el constructor pero ahora tengo problemas con un metodo llamado devolver libro que lo he hecho igual pero con remove... No sé me borran los libros! Pero muchas gracias por la ayuda en serio @sanbope !